Typescript: index signature needed in all my subclasses?
My example code can be found here: https://playcode.io/2184949
Explanation:

My BaseAPI class is an abstract class to manage the classes of different API (eg. TransactionAPI)
In the APImanager class I keep a registry of all my endpoints. For this, I have a getEndpoints method which looks for all the possible endpoints in an API class.
The typescript errors told me to add an index signature in the BaseAPI class.

But I cannot make my code run without typescript errors if I don't add the index signature to each subclass (eg index signature removed in file-api ==> Error on line 32 of base-api.ts).
BugFinder: Argument of type 'typeof FileAPI' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof BaseAPI'.BugFinder: 
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'typeof FileAPI'.

Can I change my code in a way so I don't need to duplicate the index signature in each subclass of the abstract baseAPI class?
This is my code:
base-api.ts
import { FileAPI } from './file-api';
import { TransactionAPI } from './transaction-api';

export abstract class BaseAPI {
  static readonly [key: string]:
    | ApiCall<unknown> // Defines a single API call with a generic response type
    | { [subKey: string]: ApiCall<unknown> } // Nested API call definitions
    | undefined // Supports optional static members
    | (() => string);

  // Static method example
  static getChannel(): string {
    return 'This is a static method';
  }
}

export interface ApiCall<T> {
  method: string; // HTTP method like POST, GET, etc.
  endpoint: string; // Endpoint path
  response: string
}

export class ApiManager {
  public static readonly endpointsRegistry: string[] = [
    ...this.getEndpoints(TransactionAPI),
    ...this.getEndpoints(FileAPI),
  ];

  private static getEndpoints(api: typeof BaseAPI): string[] {
    const endpoints: string[] = [];

    const extractEndpoints = (obj: { [key: string]: unknown }) => {
     // implementation not relevant
    };

    extractEndpoints(api);
    return endpoints;
  }
}


transaction-api.ts
import { ApiCall, ApiResponse, BaseAPI } from './api-manager';

export class TransactionAPI extends BaseAPI {
  // Explicitly add the index signature to satisfy BaseAPI's requirements
  static readonly [key: string]:
    | ApiCall<unknown>
    | { [subKey: string]: ApiCall<unknown> }
    | undefined
    | (() => string);

  public static getChannel() {
    return '';
  }

  public static readonly CREATE: ApiCall<Transaction> = {
    method: 'POST',
    endpoint: 'transaction',
    response: {} as ApiResponse<Transaction>, // Placeholder for response
  };
}

export class Transaction {
  id!: number;
  transactionDate!: Date;
  amount!: number;
}


file-api.ts
import { ApiCall, ApiResponse, BaseAPI } from './api-manager';

export class FileAPI extends BaseAPI {
  public static getChannel() {
    return '';
  }
  public static readonly CREATE: ApiCall<File> = {
    method: 'POST',
    endpoint: 'file',
    response: {} as ApiResponse<File>, // Placeholder for response
  };
}

export class File {
  name!: string; // File name with extension
  mimeType!: string; // MIME type of the file (e.g., text/csv, application/pdf)
  size!: number; // Size of the file in bytes
  data!: string; // Base64-encoded file content
}



@jcalz: I added the code examples.

Thanks. That's at least 100 lines of code. Could you make it a [mre] that demonstrates your problem without things unrelated to it? You're only asking about index signature stuff, not the rest of your code. You could probably demonstrate the whole thing with a single parent class and a single subclass, where the only pieces present are the index signature pieces, couldn't you?

Okay, minimality aside for now, does this approach meet your needs? I think you're running into ms/TS#50183 and all I can think of doing here other than adding an idx sig to each subclass, is to make your function allow anything which is "compatible" with the index signature. If that works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz: This looks like a solution indeed. But can you please explain?

I don’t understand the “but” in that sentence. Are you saying you need more of an explanation in the comments before you could decide if I should write an answer with an explanation?

No, you can forget about the but  Please write your answer with explanation...

As you've discovered, if a class has a static index signature, it is not inherited by subclasses. I'm not sure why this is the case, but it's reported at microsoft/TypeScript#50183 and classified as a suggestion awaiting community feedback. If you want to see this changed and you think your use case is compelling, you might want to give that issue a  and leave a comment describing your use case.
Obviously you could go ahead and explicitly add an index signature to each subclass. Another approach is to have your function check not directly for typeof BaseAPI, but for a generic type "compatible" with typeof BaseAPI, such that if it was given an implicit index signature it would be accepted.  TypeScript intentionally doesn't give implicit index signatures to interface types (and apparently this is also true for the type of a class constructor declaration), see microsoft/TypeScript#15300.
I'll make a utility type called InxSigCompatible<T, U> where T is a type with a string-keyed index signature (maybe this could be altered for other index signatures) and U is the type to check. It will work by first removing the index signature from T via WithoutIdx:
type WithoutIdx<T> =
  { [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : K]: T[K] }

(That's a key-remapped mapped type that suppresses the key if it's explicitly string.) And after that we check U against WithoutIdx<T> and then for each key in U which isn't already a key of WithoutIdx<T>, we add a property corresponding to the index signature of T:
type IdxSigCompatible<T, U> = WithoutIdx<T> &
{ [K in keyof U as K extends keyof WithoutIdx<T> ? never : K & string]:
  T[K & keyof T] };

So if U extends IdxSigCompatible<T, U>, then U is "index signature compatible" with T.  As a brief example: if T is {a: string, [k: string]: string | number} and U is {a: string, b: string, c: number}, then WithoutIdx<T> is {a: string}.  And then IdxSigCompatible<T, U> is {a: string} & {b: string | number, c: string | number}. Since U is assignable to that, it works. But if U were {a: string, b: string, c: Date}, then the c property would fail to be assignable since it's not string | number.
The idea is we're sort of replacing T's index signature with any excess properties from U, and checking them.

So once we do that, we can change your APIManager's getEndpoints() method to look like:
private static getEndpoints<T extends IdxSigCompatible<typeof BaseAPI, T>>(
  api: T): string[] { /* ⋯ */ }

And now the check will work:
public static readonly endpointsRegistry: string[] = [
  ...this.getEndpoints(TransactionAPI), // okay
  ...this.getEndpoints(FileAPI), // okay
];

If you examine what is happening with those calls, let's say getEndpoints(FileAPI), you'll see:
// (method) ApiManager.getEndpoints<typeof FileAPI>(api: typeof FileAPI): string[]

And the constraint on T there looks like IdxSigCompatible<typeof BaseAPI, typeof FileAPI>, which is:
type ConstraintFileAPI = IdxSigCompatible<typeof BaseAPI, typeof FileAPI>
/* type ConstraintFileAPI = WithoutIdx<typeof BaseAPI> & {
    readonly CREATE: ApiCall<unknown> | {
        [subKey: string]: ApiCall<unknown>;
    } | (() => string) | undefined;
} */

or, more clearly:
/* type ConstraintFileAPI = {
    prototype: BaseAPI;
    getChannel: () => string;
    readonly CREATE: ApiCall<unknown> | {
        [subKey: string]: ApiCall<unknown>;
    } | (() => string) | undefined;
}

Since typeof FileAPI is assignable to ConstraintFileAPI, it works.  If you make a bad call it will fail:
static whoops = this.getEndpoints(Date); // error!
// Argument of type 'DateConstructor' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// 'IdxSigCompatible<typeof BaseAPI, DateConstructor>'. 'getChannel' is missing

static stillWhoops = this.getEndpoints(class Foo { // error!
  static getChannel() { return "" };
  static badProp: 123
}) // Types of property 'badProp' are incompatible.

Yes, this is complicated. So if you do decide to comment on microsoft/TypeScript#50183, you might want to mention that trying to work around the lack of inheritance isn't ideal.
Playground link to code
